# Change field name when serializing to JSON in Groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I'm using JsonOutput to serialize POGO into JSON. Is there any option to set name alternative for particular field?

```
class MyObject {
  def myField = "test" // in JSON I want to have myJsonField instead of myField
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you wont be able to transform the field name using JsonOutput, but you can easily use [`JsonBuilder`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html) to create your own transformation of name of the fields as shown below:

```
import groovy.json.*

class MyObject {
  def myField = "test"
  def otherField = "other"
}

def obj = new MyObject()
assert JsonOutput.toJson(obj) == /{"otherField":"other","myField":"test"}/

def builder = new JsonBuilder()
builder {
    obj.properties.each { prop ->
        if( !(prop.key in ['class', 'declaringClass', 'metaClass'] ) ) {
            ( prop.key == 'myField' ) ? 
                myJsonField( "$prop.value" ) : 
                    "$prop.key"( "$prop.value" )
        }
    }
}

assert builder.toString() == /{"otherField":"other","myJsonField":"test"}/
```

**UPDATE**
Or without `JsonBuilder` but `JsonOutput`:

```
def transform = { object ->
    object.properties.collectEntries{key, value ->
        !( key in ['class', 'declaringClass', 'metaClass'] ) ? 
            key == 'myField' ? 
                ['myJsonField', value] : [key, value] : 
                    [:]
    }
}
assert JsonOutput.toJson(transform(obj)) == 
                     /{"otherField":"other","myJsonField":"test"}/
```

Comment: I know solution with JsonBuilder but definitely prefer JsonOutput (of course if it will be possible)

Comment: @JakubK You can try [JsonProperty](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.1.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonProperty.html) from Jackson API like [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6817690/) to see if you get what you need from that annotation.